# Why $\{x:f(x)>a\}\cap\{x:g(x)\le a-\varepsilon\} = \{x:|f(x)-g(x)|\gt\varepsilon\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Why $\{x:f(x)>a\}\cap\{x:g(x)\le a-\varepsilon\} = \{x:|f(x)-g(x)|\gt\varepsilon\}$, for $\varepsilon\gt0$.

I can guess this relationship. However, I can't make the right set from the left set using mathematical equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two sets are not necessarily equal, but rather
$$ \{x:f(x)>a\}\cap\{x:g(x)\leq a-\varepsilon\}\subset\{x:|f(x)-g(x)|>\varepsilon\}$$
This is because if $f(x)>a$ and $g(x)\leq a-\varepsilon$, then
$$ |f(x)-g(x)|=f(x)-g(x)>a-(a-\varepsilon)=\varepsilon$$

It's possible to have $f(x)\leq a$ and $|f(x)-g(x)|>\varepsilon$ (for instance), which is why the sets may not be equal.

Comment: Ah.... Thank you very much. equality doesn't hold!!! I got it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Without more information, this is false. Define $f,g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ by $f(x):=\alpha-\frac\epsilon4$ and $g(x):=\alpha+\epsilon.$ Then the left-hamd side is the empty set and the right-hand side is the set of all real numbers.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am proving the wrong equation! The left hand side was a subset of the right hand side as carmichael561 answered.

Answer (score 1):

The correct statement would be 
$$
\bigcup_{a \in \mathbb R} \{x:f(x)>a\}\cap\{x:g(x)\le a-\varepsilon\} = \{x:f(x)-g(x)\gt\varepsilon\}.
$$
The inclusion ($\subseteq$) has been proven by carmichael561. For the reverse one, if $|f(x) - g(x)| > \varepsilon$, let $a = \frac{f(x)+g(x)}2$. Since $f(x) > g(x) + \varepsilon \ge g(x)$, we have $f(x) > a$. Since $f(x) - \varepsilon > g(x)$, we have $a-\varepsilon > g(x)$.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 1):

As you have noted, the left hand side is a subset of the right-hand side. To prove this, note

$|f(x)-g(x)|\gt\varepsilon\ \Longleftrightarrow f(x) > g(x) +  \epsilon \lor f(x) < g(x) - \epsilon$.

If $x$ satisfies $f(x)>a$ and $g(x) + \epsilon \leq a$, then $f(x) > g(x) + \epsilon$. However, $x$ such that $f(x) < g(x) - \epsilon$ may be members of the set on the right-hand side but not the left.